# Emacs M-x zone command stops ends right as I start typing, is this correct?

Tags: emacs

From what I read, the M-x zone was supposed to 'help' you from stopping zoning out, and run when you leave emacs unactive. For me, when I type M-x zone, emacs instantly begins randomly moving my text in the text box, and as soon as I start typing it ends, and never does it again. This doesn't seem right to me. Is this the way it is supposed to run? I am using the Windows OS version of emacs, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is the function you are looking for is

```
M-x zone-when-ide
```

Moving text around is one of the possible "screensavers" that will be run by zone, so the observed behavior should be pretty fine.

```
M-x zone
```

Will only start once if you activate and stop as soon as you start typing. Use zone-when-idle as mentioned above if you want it to restart on its own.